# Azure Pipeline gradle build local.properties' could not be found

Tags: android, gradle, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

> The file '/Users/runner/work/1/s/local.properties' could not be found

I am going through the azure pipeline for my Android project. But I am stuck on the gradle build step[image]

line 31 say local.properties could not be found, which make sense because it is in gitignore. But then azure didn't give any instruction on what to do with this error.

As for the pipeline yaml, I am using the default template for android
[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Upload the file to azure secure file https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=azure-devops

Comment: The entire local.properties file?

Comment: yes, then in the yaml you need to download the file back to the position where gradle expect this folder to be  BEFORE the assemble task. (link has instruction)

Answer (score 2):

I am facing the same issue now. And I resolved it by creating a local.properties.

```
- task: file-creator@6
inputs:
  filepath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/local.properties'
  filecontent: 
'sdk.dir=C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk'
  fileoverwrite: true
```